# Some Strings Won't Decrypt

Tags: php, string, encryption

I have a function to encrypt and decrypt a string with a salt/password, but there's an issue, I have no problem encrypting any string, but with decrpyting it has a problem decrypting some strings...

For example it will decrypt "Hello World", but not "Login" or "RedeemToken"... The code i'm using is below with some outputs and debugging stuff:

```
function encrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}

function decrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}
```

Also the functions above are used like this:

```
echo encrypt($string);
echo decrypt($string);
```

Example of some strings that encrypt, but will not encrypt:

```
Login - Doesn't Decrypt
RedeemToken - Doesn't Decrypt
Blacklist - Decrypt Works
Email - Decrypt Works
```

If anyone can point out the issue or help, please let me know, thanks!

HERE IS MY CODE:

USE - `"http://example.com/test.php?st=xeJuD3+A0Po="`

```
<?php

$string123 = mysql_escape_string($_GET["st"]);

echo decrypt($string123);

function encrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}

function decrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo decrypt(<STRING>);`? Where does `<STRING>` come from? It should be the ciphertext that you got from `encrypt`

Comment: @ArtjomB. I put that as a placeholder, but that's where the string goes.

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` => WTF ô_O ???

Comment: Your `echo decrypt($string);` is wrong. Decryption applies to the encrypted string, not on the original string. For example, `$encrypt_message = encrypt("Login"); echo decrypt($encrypt_message);`

Comment: @Blag I was seeing if that was the issue, but it wasn't

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I know, the `$string` is already decrypted, it just needs to be encrypted, not sure why it doesn't work...

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Everything is decrypted with this exact code. Which PHP version do you have?

Comment: @ArtjomB. PHP 5.4, but the functions work perfectly, but it just doesnt decrypt some strings for example `xeJuD3+A0Po=` which is `Login` encrypted, but `AA/PpTmKWjY=` which is `Email`, can get decrypted back to `Email`...

Comment: `$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');`=> this is useless no ?

Comment: @Blag Yes I believe so, haha, but I don't think that narrows down the issue?

Comment: @TymeBomb, But on my system I'm able to decrypt `AA/PpTmKWjY=` back to `Email` using your `decrypt` function. Weird.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul As I said Email works, but Login and RedeemToken, doen't... Some strings just don't work...

Comment: it work on my php to, so it's strange u_u show your test code please ?

Comment: [Don't use `mcrypt`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong). [Use something from this list instead](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

Comment: @TymeBomb found, answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found ;)

In your URL, use `http://example.com/test.php?st=xeJuD3%2BA0Po%3D` as `=+` and other char are not allowed tu be used in URL.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.rawurlencode.php to craft right URL from your base64 encrypted data

If you can't change the URL before it hit PHP, you'll have to change back the space in `+` :

```
$_GET['st'] = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['st']);
```

And BTW, remove the `$string123 = mysql_escape_string($_GET["st"]);` mysql_ is for mysql, nothing else, it's not a magic spell you cast everywhere. the only thing it does is change `'` to `\'` and it wont help you anywhere; even in MySQL it's now depreciated and you need to use PDO or mysqli

---

for this :

```
<?php
function encrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}

function decrypt($data)
{
    $secret = "FUSIONIDISTOPNOTCHCODEDBYMELTYNET";
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}

echo "'". ($a = encrypt('Email'))."'<br>\n";
echo "'".decrypt($a)."'<br>\n";
echo "'".decrypt('AA/PpTmKWjY=')."'<br>\n";
echo "'".($e= encrypt('Login'))."'<br>\n";
echo "'".decrypt($e)."'<br>\n";
echo "'".decrypt('xeJuD3+A0Po=')."'<br>\n";
```

I get :

```
'AA/PpTmKWjY='
'Email'
'Email'
'xeJuD3+A0Po='
'Login'
'Login'
```

So, for me it work fine...

Comment: I used this:
`$string123 = mysql_escape_string($_GET["st"]);`
`echo encrypt($string123)." - ".decrypt($string123);`
And the output is this when I try to decrypt `Login` Encypted already: `3RrkEHf2uUCHszJz68+PLQ== -` the decrypted part is blank, why is that? Also what version of PHP do you use?

Comment: you understand that you try to decrypt your unencrypted var ? <_>"

Comment: Don't use the f*********** `mysql_` plz; you don't need it, it's useless (and take [a look](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) at the red box )

Comment: I mean't when I do `echo decrypt("xeJuD3+A0Po=");` it displays a blank string nothing shows up, but if I do any other string they work...

Comment: what this print you : `echo "'".decrypt('xeJuD3+A0Po=')."'<br>\n";` ?

Comment: It works like that, I think there is an issue with the get statement... it must have to do with the get and decrypting: `$EncryptedAction = $_GET["Action"];
$Action = decrypt($EncryptedAction);` After that it brakes and nothing gets displayed...

Comment: `var_dump($_GET["Action"]);` print you what ?

Comment: `string(24) "vBrbF9oPzAI1YQ7isT1t8g=="`

Comment: `echo "'".decrypt("vBrbF9oPzAI1YQ7isT1t8g==")."'<br>\n";` => `'something'` so it work for me... try `echo decrypt($_GET["Action"]);`

Comment: I already tried that and that doesn't work only seems it works if you do `decrypt("xeJuD3+A0Po=");` and `decrypt($_GET["Action"]);` doesn't work, not sure what the issue is at all :(

Comment: update your post with your code; as It work for me, it's in your code, and even probably a really dumb mistake that you miss and do again every time...

Comment: Added my code and how I use it, it's in my original post above, let me know, thanks!

Comment: Thing is I can't add that because It's sent from an application to the php directly and randomly, so there's no way to do that, is there anything to bypass the illegal chars in the link without manually doing it?

Comment: this is what you get in php : `array(1) { ["st"]=> string(12) "xeJuD3 A0Po=" } ` note the space instead of `+` so this : `$_GET['st'] = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['st']);` will do the trick (update my answer)